# how to define checkbox within the label in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel-4

my current code

```
 {{Form::label('remember','Remember Me')}}
 {{ Form::checkbox('remember', 1, null, ['id'=>'remember', 'class' => 'className']) }}
```

which is producing html

```
   <label for="remember">Remember Me</label>
   <input id="remember" class="className" name="remember" value="1" type="checkbox">
```

But i wan it to work like:

```
<label for="remember">Remember Me
       <input id="remember" class="className" name="remember" value="1" type="checkbox">
 </label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a macro for this!

```
{{ Form::macro('myField', function($name,$value = 1, $id= null, $class, $label) {
return '<label for="'.$name.'">'.$label.'
        <input id="'.$id.'" class="'.$class.'" name="'.$name.'" value="'.$value.'" type="checkbox">
        </label>';
}); }}
```

Call it like this:

```
 {{ Form::myField('name','value','id', 'className', 'label') }}
```

---

I've found some bootstrap styled macros here: [credits to JONOB laravel.io](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=11960)

**Here are some bootstrap style macros:**

```
Form::macro('textField', function($name, $label = null, $value = null, $attributes = array())
{
    $element = Form::text($name, $value, fieldAttributes($name, $attributes));

    return fieldWrapper($name, $label, $element);
});

Form::macro('passwordField', function($name, $label = null, $attributes = array())
{
    $element = Form::password($name, fieldAttributes($name, $attributes));

    return fieldWrapper($name, $label, $element);
});

Form::macro('textareaField', function($name, $label = null, $value = null, $attributes = array())
{
    $element = Form::textarea($name, $value, fieldAttributes($name, $attributes));

    return fieldWrapper($name, $label, $element);
});

Form::macro('selectField', function($name, $label = null, $options, $value = null, $attributes = array())
{
    $element = Form::select($name, $options, $value, fieldAttributes($name, $attributes));

    return fieldWrapper($name, $label, $element);
});

Form::macro('selectMultipleField', function($name, $label = null, $options, $value = null, $attributes = array())
{
    $attributes = array_merge($attributes, ['multiple' => true]);
    $element = Form::select($name, $options, $value, fieldAttributes($name, $attributes));

    return fieldWrapper($name, $label, $element);
});

Form::macro('checkboxField', function($name, $label = null, $value = 1, $checked = null, $attributes = array())
{
    $attributes = array_merge(['id' => 'id-field-' . $name], $attributes);

    $out = '<div class="checkbox';
    $out .= fieldError($name) . '">';
    $out .= '<label>';
    $out .= Form::checkbox($name, $value, $checked, $attributes) . ' ' . $label;
    $out .= '</div>';

    return $out;
});

function fieldWrapper($name, $label, $element)
{
    $out = '<div class="form-group';
    $out .= fieldError($name) . '">';
    $out .= fieldLabel($name, $label);
    $out .= $element;
    $out .= '</div>';

    return $out;
}

function fieldError($field)
{
    $error = '';

    if ($errors = Session::get('errors'))
    {
        $error = $errors->first($field) ? ' has-error' : '';
    }

    return $error;
}

function fieldLabel($name, $label)
{
    if (is_null($label)) return '';

    $name = str_replace('[]', '', $name);

    $out = '<label for="id-field-' . $name . '" class="control-label">';
    $out .= $label . '</label>';

    return $out;
}

function fieldAttributes($name, $attributes = array())
{
    $name = str_replace('[]', '', $name);

    return array_merge(['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'id-field-' . $name], $attributes);
}
```

Comment: Cheers mate! Those macros are really helpful. @Rafael

Comment: There will be more in a second. @Naeem